# How can one avoid expansion errors in functions killing the shell?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I ran into a surprising behavior in one of my shell scripts today.  It is demonstrated by the following example:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

do_it() {
  shopt -s failglob
  {
    rm killme.*
    echo "and then ..."
  } 2>/dev/null || echo "glob error"

  echo "life goes on ..."
}

do_it || echo "function failed"
```

The idea in the original script was that I wanted to allow glob expansion errors to occur for a particular command so as to avoid executing that one command when there were no arguments, yet *detect* that error and take alternative action.  My expectation was that when `killme.*` did not match anything, executing the above script via

```
./test.sh || echo "script failed"
```

would emit

```
glob error
life goes on ...
```

or maybe

```
function failed
```

.  It didn't (with Bash 4.2.46).  Instead it printed

```
script failed
```

.  While troubleshooting the issue, I discovered something even more curious: if I simplify the script further by eliminating the function, the behavior changes.  That is, consider this alternative script:

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s failglob

{
  rm killme.*
  echo "and then ..."
} 2>/dev/null || echo "glob error"

echo "life goes on ..."
```

If I run *that* via

```
./test2.sh || echo "script failed"
```

, it prints

```
life goes on ...
```

There seem to be some other weird variations when a function like the one in the first script is called in a loop, but I haven't fully characterized that.

**Questions**:

1. Is this documented behavior?  My examination of the Bash manual has been unavailing.  It specifies that an "expansion error" occurs, and it seems natural that that's a *shell* error, not an error in the command, but if there's anything by which I should be able to predict the details of the observed results then I've missed it.
2. I can solve the issue by running the expansion in a subshell, but is there any lighter weight workaround?  I guess I could perform the expansion in advance, with `failglob` unset, and test the result, but that's messy and contains a race condition.

Comment: There's always a race condition. If someone deletes all the matches between the time the shell expands the wildcard and when the command actually runs, it will get an error.

Comment: Yes, @Barmar, but they will get *different* errors in those two cases.  In particular, whether the shell or the command errors will differ.

Comment: you may have better luck using 'shopt -s nullglob' ... I'll put context in an answer because the comments are limited :-)

Comment: The documentation says that in POSIX mode, "Non-interactive shells exit if a parameter expansion error occurs"; but I don't see any difference between your two scripts that should cause test.sh to use POSIX mode and test2.sh not. (And testing locally, I find that adding `set -o posix` to test2.sh, or `set +o posix` to test.sh, does not affect the behavior.)

Comment: Thanks, @ruakh.  Mine is not a *parameter* expansion error, so perhaps that explains why bash's handling of it is independent of whether POSIX mode is enabled.  It appears, however, that unlike bash, POSIX does not distinguish between  different kinds of expansion errors.  bash's behavior with my `test.sh` seems to be [POSIX-conformant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01).  Its behavior with `test2.sh`, not.  I'm probably going to just use a subshell for my particular problem, as that seems safest.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Whoops, good point. I searched the documentation for "expansion error" and found the only relevant-seeming part, not noticing that it's actually *not* relevant. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this documented behavior? My examination of the Bash manual has been unavailing. It specifies that an "expansion error" occurs, and it
>      seems natural that that's a shell error, not an error in the command,
>      but if there's anything by which I should be able to predict the
>      details of the observed results then I've missed it.

Neither the current version of the Bash manual nor the manual for the version on which I discovered the problem seems to document the behavior that should be expected when pathname expansion results in an expansion error.  Some versions of the manual do document behavior when an error occurs during *parameter* expansion, and apparently that varies between some Bash versions and depending on whether Bash is running in POSIX mode.

POSIX itself, however, does not distinguish between different varieties of expansion error.  It [specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) that (all) expansion errors in non-interactive shells cause the shell to terminate with a diagnostic.  This is the behavior exhibited by my **test.sh**, but it conflicts with the behavior exhibited by my **test2.sh**.

Inasmuch as Bash does not claim to be fully POSIX-conformant, especially when not running in POSIX-compatibility mode, the discrepancy with POSIX cannot be considered a bug, but the surprising and undocumented inconsistency between the behavior of the two scripts certainly seems buggy to me, so I have filed an issue about it.

> 2. I can solve the issue by running the expansion in a subshell, but is there any lighter weight workaround? I guess I could perform the
>      expansion in advance, with failglob unset, and test the result, but
>      that's messy and contains a race condition.

Inasmuch as the POSIX shell is expected to terminate on expansion errors, and Bash does this in at least some contexts, the only safe way to enable recovery from expansion errors seems to be to cause the error to occur in a subshell.

In my particular case, I want to ensure that the command does not run with zero arguments or with an unexpanded glob as an argument, as it may do the wrong thing in these cases.  It is OK, though, if the command runs with arguments designating files that disappear after expansion but before the command tries to operate on the arguments.  The simplest and most reliable way to accomplish seems to be to just run the command in a subshell in which the `failglob` option is set.

It would also be possible to pre-expand the glob with `failglob` unset, test whether it is empty, and then use the pre-expanded result instead of expanding the glob again.  That seems like overkill for my purposes, so I have opted to go with the subshell.

**Update**

As @eurythmia pointed out in his answer, Bash's behavior is even stranger than I thought.  In **test1.sh**, the expansion error does not cause the whole *script* to terminate; rather, it causes the *pipeline* containing the `do_it` call to fail immediately, altogether bypassing any consideration of the success or failure of the function call command itself, and for that reason not executing the `echo` command.  For all intents and purposes, the `do_it` call itself neither succeeds nor fails, which is highly peculiar at best.

That does not, however, change the conclusions presented in this answer: the behavior is definitely not documented for Bash, and it is inconsistent with POSIX.  The simplest safe alternative is to isolate any use of the `failglob` option inside a subshell, but if that's impractical for some reason then there are workarounds.

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing in your test.sh is not the shell terminating. As explained in the answer below, bash is jumping to the top level shell context and failing the *command*. The command you're using is a composite command, so the shell script returns an error. Simply adding another command afterwards will show that the shell hasn't *terminated*, it merely failed the command and moved on to the next one.

Comment: This answer is being discussed on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375620/what-do-i-do-when-a-user-doesnt-like-my-answer-so-they-write-their-own-and-acce

Answer (score 4):

As the context for my above comment ... you can use a variable with shell globbing to check if a file with the pattern exists, and remove them all if they do, else print out the error message. This leaves you without depending on an error state to trigger the "this didn't work" message.

```
shopt -s nullglob
a=(killme.*)
if [[ -n $a ]]; then
 rm killme.* > /dev/null 2>&1
 echo "life goes on ...
else
  echo "glob error"
fi
```

... I can't (at present) offer any insight into why the function is failing, other than the rumination that perhaps function calls are executed as subshells.

**Edit**:
I found this gem in `bash`'s `subst.c` ... it looks like we jump up to the top shell context, discarding all current context, and set the failure code:

```
  else if (fail_glob_expansion != 0)
    {
      last_command_exit_value = EXECUTION_FAILURE;
      report_error (_("no match: %s"), tlist->word->word);
      exp_jump_to_top_level (DISCARD);
    }
```

... in this case, I suspect that bash is parsing `doit || echo "function failed"` as a *single* command, causing the whole bit to fail. Since `bash` returns the exit code of the last command in a script, that explains why you're seeing your script 'fail' (i.e. `./my_script.sh || echo "script failed"` is printing "script failed").

You can see that if you add `echo "exit_code: $?"` as the last line of your script it will print a non-zero code (i.e. failure), but your script will return a success code:

```
[eurythmia@localhost ~]$ cat ./test_script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

do_it() {
  shopt -s failglob
  {
    rm killme.*
    echo "and then ..."
  } >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "glob error"

  echo "life goes on ..."
} 

do_it || echo "function failed"
echo "exit code: $?"
[eurythmia@localhost ~]$ ./test_script.sh || echo "I failed"
exit code: 1
[eurythmia@localhost ~]$ echo $?
0
[eurythmia@localhost ~]$
```

I guess this all comes down to how bash parses, and what it considers to be a 'command' (something that I'm going to look further into, for my own edification). In the meantime, I would not depend on `shopt -s failglob` from within a function. Viable alternatives include using `shopt -s failglob` from the root level of the script, or sticking to the standard test operators (which are implemented as bash builtins) when working inside functions.

Comment: No, function calls aren't implicitly executed as subshells (in the OP's case here, at least; there are lots of ways to make that happen, but they involve pipes, command substitutions, or other operations that create a subshell themselves).

Comment: I didn't think it would be the case that the function calls would implicitly happen in a subshell, but I haven't had the time to check and see if that was the case. Thanks @CharlesDuffy :-)

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in the question, I prefer not to pre-test.  In fact, the point is that I want to *ensure* that the command does not run if the glob doesn't match anything.  It's ok for the command to fail if the matching files disappear after the glob is expanded, but the command will do the wrong thing if the glob expands to nothing.  It's less risky in this case (albeit not without risk) to just let the glob fail to expand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I went back and re-read the question, apparently I misinterpreted that bit. I can confirm that I'm seeing the same behaviour as you with bash 4.4.23(1). removing the redirect to `/dev/null` shows that it's failing to match the glob as you would expect, but the failure result is ... well, mystifying. I would suggest raising a bug with bash (you can use the `bashbug` command line tool to do this), because this doesn't look like it should be happening. I might dig into this more tomorrow as it's an interesting problem :-)